# libgdx Can't Resolve Symbol Android

Tags: java, android

I just started coding with libgdx and have encountered a problem. Android Studio does not allow me to import android, I tried 'Invalidate Caches' and other solutions but nothing appears to work. 
Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.shaimenzin.game.FlappyBirdGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new FlappyBirdGame(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Android Studio does not allow me to import android"? Do you have any error message you can paste?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'android' in the import line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cases of Cannot resolve symbol 'android' error in Android studio, you can simply delete the iml files inside your project folder.

Try this:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Go to your project directory and make a backup somewhere on your PC.
3. Remove the .idea folder and .iml files in your project folder.
4. Start Android Studio and import your project from the import option in the startup.

Comment: Thanks! seems like the module was wrong, simply change the module sdk.